# Visual Studio 2015 Debug under a different domain account

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I need to run unit tests and test database connections using integrated security with SQL Server for a domain service account that will be the appPoolIdentity when we push to dev and production. I have been trying to find an answer to this for some time and can't seem to get a handle on it. It seems like it should be possible to impersonate this account given userid and password. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively simple.  Rather than using the integrated IIS Express, you install the full IIS on your local computer, then you assign the app pool the identity of the service account you are going to use.

You do need to run Visual Studio as Administrator in this scenario to debug a different user.

Make sure that you setup the project to use IIS rather than IIS Express, and you should be good to go.